# Monero Wallet Gui not connecting to remote node

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui

I have a problem with the Monero Wallet gui v0.11.1.0. After opening the wallet, I go to Setting and make sure that the daemon is stopped. Then in the Daemon address fields I have node.moneroworld.com with port 18089, but when I press Connect nothing happens.

```
cat ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log
```

gives me

```
2018-01-14 11:56:33.055     7f94e056e780    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:148   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2018-01-14 11:56:33.056     7f94e056e780    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
```

It seems that it doesn't care about the Daemon address fields.

When I try with monero-wallet-cli I get this:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address node.moneroworld.com:18089 --wallet-file /mnt/data/Monero/wallets/...
...
Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: node.moneroworld.com:18089. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or restart the wallet with the correct daemon address.
Error: wallet failed to connect to daemon: node.moneroworld.com:18089. Daemon either is not started or wrong port was passed. Please make sure daemon is running or restart the wallet with the correct daemon address.
```

also

```
nmap -p 18089 node.moneroworld.com
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-14 16:47 EET
Failed to resolve "node.moneroworld.com".
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
```

Is there a problem with the DNS of node.moneroworld.com?
Os is Ubuntu.
Please help, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a different remote node?

Comment: Yes, I tried all from here https://moneroworld.com/, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a local problem then?

Comment: Possibly, I used an IP from this list http://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/?domain=node.moneroworld.com and it worked. I think it is a problem resolving the DNS, not sure why...